# How can I export tables to Excel from a simple text source?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, emacs

**Question**

If someone asks for a document and specifies that it must be a Word
document, even though it will be so simple it will only have a few
section headings, I thankfully do not have to use Word from my side
and can write the text file

```
= Title

== Introduction
text

== Body
text

== Conclusion
text
```

and process it with [asciidoctor](http://asciidoctor.org)
followed by [pandoc](https://pandoc.org)
to obtain the requisite .docx file.

Now suppose someone asks for a few numbers and specifies that they must
be in an Excel document just because the numbers will be organized in a
table, how can I generate such a file from a text-only source on my side?

**Emacs**

In Emacs I can use

- SES mode,
- csv-mode (C-x C-a and C-x C-u are particularly helpful),
- M-x table-insert,
- or even just rectangle operations (C-x r t, etc).

Is there a way to export any of these to the Excel (XML) format?

**----Not looking for...----**

**Other spreadsheets**

I am familiar with Google Sheets. Here I am not asking for replacing a
spreadsheet program with another spreadsheet program. I am asking whether
there exists a toolchain (similar to asciidoctor + pandoc) that will
reliably generate a spreadsheet when the data are supremely simple.

**Online services**

I am also not interested in web-based services that perform the conversion. This would be a poor option, both because of the loss of privacy, and because Excel sheets can include VBA code. VBA code is perhaps constrained, I'm not sure. Still, this is an unpalatable option.

Comment: @CharlieRB ... and likewise, recursively. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CSV,

There are several tools out there depending on your platform/environment.

For linux there is: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssconvert
there are several online converters, and if you have access to use a spreadsheet application most can open and save as .xls(x).

python pandas can also read and write both so a very quick script could also be used:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
pd.DataFrame(file).to_excel("output.xls")
```

or for those line counters:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("test.csv")).to_excel("output.xls")
```

Comment: You are headed in the right direction with this answer, but it needs much more detail. Can you give a brief explanation how to do what you are suggesting?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder of how helpful csv-mode can be. I updated the question. Can you suggest a reliable toolchain for converting a CSV file to an Excel file?

Comment: A three-liner in Python (using pandas) is a great option! Looking into it...

Comment: On macOS ssconvert is available (http://www.rumbud.com/d/how-to-install-gnumeric-and-other-linux-apps-on-mac-osx/) via Homebrew. Though it's a lousy option because it depends on XQuartz (which is needed by Gnumeric).